# Python - Most elegant way to extract a substring, being given left and right borders

Tags: python, string, find

I have a string - Python :

```
string = "/foo13546897/bar/Atlantis-GPS-coordinates/bar457822368/foo/"
```

Expected output is :

```
"Atlantis-GPS-coordinates"
```

I know that the expected output is ALWAYS surrounded by "/bar/" on the left and "/" on the right :

```
"/bar/Atlantis-GPS-coordinates/"
```

Proposed solution would look like :

```
a = string.find("/bar/")
b = string.find("/",a+5)
output=string[a+5,b]
```

This works, but I don't like it.
Does someone know a beautiful function or tip ?

Comment: `string.split("/bar/")[1].split("/")[0]`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> string.split("/bar/")[1].split("/")[0]
'Atlantis-GPS-coordinates'
```

Some efficiency from adding a max split of `1` I suppose:

```
>>> string.split("/bar/", 1)[1].split("/", 1)[0]
'Atlantis-GPS-coordinates'
```

Or use [partition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> string.partition("/bar/")[2].partition("/")[0]
'Atlantis-GPS-coordinates'
```

Or a regex:

```
>>> re.search(r'/bar/([^/]+)', string).group(1)
'Atlantis-GPS-coordinates'
```

Depends on what speaks to you and your data.

Comment: Love your answer.  I will validate it. What are the advantages / drawbacks of split and partition ?

Comment: The main difference is how each handles the split if `/bar/` is not present. `partition` always produces a three element tuple with empty strings of the partition element is not found. `split` changes the number of elements in the list produced. It is easier to test whether `partition` did what it was supposed to do. I would use `split` if I knew the string would successfully split; `partition` or a regex if I needed to test.

Answer (score 4):

What you haven't isn't all that bad.  I'd write it as:

```
start = string.find('/bar/') + 5
end = string.find('/', start)
output = string[start:end]
```

as long as you know that `/bar/WHAT-YOU-WANT/` is always going to be present.  Otherwise, I would reach for the [regular expression knife](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re):

```
>>> import re
>>> PATTERN = re.compile('^.*/bar/([^/]*)/.*$')
>>> s = '/foo13546897/bar/Atlantis-GPS-coordinates/bar457822368/foo/'
>>> match = PATTERN.match(s)
>>> match.group(1)
'Atlantis-GPS-coordinates'
```

Comment: Your regex group is missing a closing parentheses

Comment: @MartinKonecny indeed.  thx

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = '(?<=/bar/).+?/'
string = "/foo13546897/bar/Atlantis-GPS-coordinates/bar457822368/foo/"

result = re.search(pattern, string)
print string[result.start():result.end() - 1]
# "Atlantis-GPS-coordinates"
```

That is a Python 2.x example. What it does first is: 
1. (?<=/bar/) means only process the following regex if this precedes it (so that /bar/ must be before it)
2. '.+?/' means any amount of characters up until the next '/' char

Hope that helps some.

If you need to do this kind of search a bunch it is better to 'compile' this search for performance, but if you only need to do it once don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` (slower than other solutions):

```sh
>>> import re
>>> string = "/foo13546897/bar/Atlantis-GPS-coordinates/bar457822368/foo/"
>>> re.search(r'(?<=/bar/)[^/]+(?=/)', string).group()
'Atlantis-GPS-coordinates'
```